# Scrape monster.com using scrapy framework

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

How can I create a crawler for monster.com for crawling all the pages. For the "next page" link, monster.com calls a javascript function but scrapy does not recognize the javascript[image: As you can see in the image]

Here is my code, it not working for pagination:

```
import scrapy
class MonsterComSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'monster.com'
    allowed_domains = ['www.monsterindia.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.monsterindia.com/data-analyst-jobs.html/']

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.css('h2.seotitle > a::attr(href)').extract()

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url =url, callback = self.parse_details)

    #crawling all the pages

        next_page_url = response.css('ul.pager > li > a::attr(althref)').extract()
        if next_page_url:
           next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url) 
           yield scrapy.Request(url = next_page_url, callback = self.parse)            


    def parse_details(self,response):
        yield {         
        'name' : response.css('h3 > a > span::text').extract()
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code throws an exception, because `next_page_url` is a `list` and `response.urljoin` method needs a string. The next page link extraction should read like this:

```
next_page_url = response.css('ul.pager > li > a::attr(althref)').extract_first()
```

(i.e. replaced `extract()` with `extract_first()`)

**EDIT:**

There is another problem with `next_page_url` extraction. All the logic is correct and pagination works, but next page link works only for the first page. It takes first `a`, but on the second page, there is also *Previous* page link. Modify the next page url extraction to this:

```
next_page_url = response.css('ul.pager').xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Next")]/@althref').extract_first()
```

Now it correctly paginates through all the pages.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this mistake,but my concern is different I wanted to know that how can I call the javascript function or pull out the html link from the javascript code to move to the next page through my crawler.

Thanks